# Google Chrome Console Error - XMLHttpRequest cannot load [URL]. Invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Trying to launch webpage `172.x.x.x/zfp` from `https://nfuse.lakesdhb.govt.nz` using google chrome.

`172.x.x.x/zfp` works on the internal network and uses the users ActiveDirectory credentials for automatic pass-through.

For external facing users (Citrix NetScaler Gateway) nfuse has an initial login screen and then it uses the same credentials to passthrough and automatically logon to `172.x.x.x/zfp` (if they are a member of a specific AD Group).

The page stops and just displays loading. From the console I see the following messages:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.x.x.x/ZFP/Dicom/UrlAuthentication?mode=StandAloneLaunch.
Invalid HTTP status code 401
```

How do I correct this issue? Please let me know if you neeed any more information. Appreciate any help you can provide.